# Retrieve email from Postfix using Java

Tags: java, smtp, imap, jakarta-mail, postfix-mta

I'm trying to find an example on how to implement a Java client (using javamail perhaps) that retrieves emails from postfix, but unfortunately I haven't found anything usable in 8 hours.
I already managed to make an smtp client to send email to my postfix server running on localhost but still no success on getting that mail I sent back. With the imap client I always get some problems with the store and get connection refused. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: And what postfix's log-file shows? Does it see the try of connection?

Answer (score 0):

Did you find the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html)?  There's lots of tips there, including tips on how to debug and what additional information we would need to see to help you figure out what's wrong.  So far all you've told us is that something's not working.  Without more details, we can't offer more than general suggestions.